# How do I alias domains using servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I'm looking to create a local domain mytest.com and have it point to my glassfish application server's web.xml

I'm coming from a php background where I'd edit my /etc/hosts file and add
127.0.0.1 mytest.com
into my file, then create an apache virtual host that looked for that domain to serve

How can I duplicate this in a java servlet environment? How can I map mytest.com in my web.xml file? I can hit my servlet from localhost:8080 just fine.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default Glassfish serves at localhost:8080. If you create an alias for 127.0.0.1 as mytest.com under /etc/hosts you can access your app using http://mytest.com:8080/contextRoot

So basically, you do all the stuffs you were doing in PHP, except you do not need to configure Apache this time. Also, you can change HTTP port from Glassfish admin console (http://localhost:4848) from 8080 to 80, to serve your application from http://mytest.com/contextRoot

Steps are as follows:

1. You start Glassfish, and deploy your web-application say, `myApp.war` or `myApp` exploded folder.
2. By Default the app will be available at, `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myApp` and all the aliases for `127.0.0.1` like `http://localhost:8080/myApp`
3. Now, you want to alias this with `myTest.com`. Go to `/etc/hosts` add an alias for 127.0.0.1 like 
   `127.0.0.1 localhost myTest.com`
4. Now, you can access your application at http://myTest.com:8080/myApp
5. However, you may further want to smoothen up things, go to `Glassfish Admin Console (http://localhost:4848) > Configuration > HTTP Service > HTTP Listeners > HTTP Listener 1 > Listener Port` change it to `80`. Now your application will be available at `http://myTest.com/myApp`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that sort of configuration is not the responsibility of the Application Server.  If you wanted to serve multiple domains from the same Application Server you would need to put a proxy or Apache in front of the Application Server.

For testing however, you should be able to simply change /etc/hosts and use `http://mytest.com:[glassfish-port]/[application context]/path/to/resource/in/app`.